# Does Amazon Fire TV support HbbTV Applications?

Tags: television, amazon-fire-tv, tal

I can't find any information about whether or not the Amazon Fire TV (*original release as of the posting of this question*) supports the **[HbbTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Broadcast_Broadband_TV)** specification.

I'm building an app using the [TAL framework](http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/getting-started/introducing-tal.html), and I've successfully added my hello world application as a web app hosted on my local server to the Amazon Fire TV, via the Web App Tester Tool.

But I am at a loss with HbbTV. Perhaps Amazon doesn't support it? I can't find any documentation that says either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no support for `HbbTV` in the box, but the TAL framework seems okay (on both original and Stick) as the BBC News app is how I get my fix most mornings in the US

As the FireTV doesn't seem to support external USB devices at the moment I'm not sure that even with a USB HbbTV you'd be able to rig something up (and the Stick has no USB port, apart from power)

I've read some folks are working on HbbTV over IP but not seen a working solution yet (though assume if there was just a local IP stream the FireTV like any Android device could work with that)